# how to add middleware in nextjs server

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to add a middleware in nextjs server like the below node express server `uploadFile.single("")`

```
app.post("/upload-excel", uploadFile.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
```

Here is the nextjs server code, where I need to add the `uploadFile.single('file')`

```
export default function handler(req: any, res: NextApiResponse<Data>) {
  });
}
```

Comment: https://dev.to/hunterbecton/middleware-in-next-js-moving-from-express-1bmf

Comment: You may want to check https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares#connectexpress-middleware-support.

Answer (score 0):

Create a _middleware file and handle based on your specific routes :

```
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const myCase =
    request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/upload-excel');
     

  if (myCase) {
    //handle here
  }

}
```

Comment: where I need to add this `uploadFile.single('file')`, uploadFile.single it came from multer package for getting files in backend